# Is there a ready jquery plugin that edits/builds html code live?

Tags: jquery, ajax

like you can see i don't even know what to search for because I can't fully explain what i need.

I have seen some websites that are offering LIVE online visual html/js editor and i need that stuff - It will be great if there is some existing AJAX & jQuery plugin for that but if not I'm ready to build that stuff.

basically what i need in there is couple of options:

- Move/Create DIV's
- Change the CSS of the DIV's (font, color, size    etc...)

Basically it's the website with some bar on the top/bottom/left/right which will have options to change the CSS and the DIV's in the website will be drag-able.

I hope someone could help me with this or at least give some useful resources on this.

**

### SOLVED

**

Comment: It's better to leave your original question here, answer that and then accept your own answer. Adding a SOLVED tag to the question you found it's answer yourself is not the way SO works.

Comment: Gotcha, ill do that right now. I still can't answer my question because i don't have 100 Rep but ill do that in 7 hours so until then its SOLVED.

Comment: even though it's "solved" I would highly recommend a program called Stylizer by Skybound for live styling of your pages, it's not an html editor you're looking for but a visual css styler

Comment: Well it doesn't meet the purpose i need it for.. (I'm 100% CSS guy so i don't really need it) The is a tool I was looking for is an online plugin with free-commerce license to integrate it in my script for other people.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest form is fill a div with content from a textarea.

```
$('textarea').keyress(function(){
    $('#sandbox').html($('textarea').val());
});
```